# how to handle events from variable number of sources?

Tags: c#

I have such class (sorry about posible mistakes, i'm writing it right here.) Class is simplified for this example, it must be more complex of course.

```
class SP500Index {

    SP500Index(List<OrderBook> stocks) {
        foreach (var stock in stocks) {
            stock.StockUpdated += stockUpdated; // how to handle?
        }
    }

}
```

So I have a lot of sources and I need to handle StockUpdated event from them. In handler I need to know `index` of stock in `stocks` list which raised the event. How to do that?

**upd** for perfomance reasons I don't want "sender look-up" instead I want index. Lookup is not trivial operation and likely involves `Hashcode` calculation `Equals` method call etc. Imagine how ofthen SP500 index changes...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just want to keep things simple. If I can avoid lookup I prefer to avoid it. Of course with current processors speed we likely can use any type of hash anywhere we want but remember that i'm writing HFT application that is pretty sensetive to any delays up to microsecond delays.

Comment: Before you optimize anything: measure first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your benchmark shows that you need the index when the event occurs you can add the index as a property to `OrderBook` and when you add an element to the list, set this property. This value will be available to the event handler.

This will work assuming that you keep the `OrderBook` objects in a single `List` and do not do any rearranging of this original list. If you have multiple lists with each object stored on only one of those lists, then you could add an `Owner` property that references the list that it is stored on.

For example...

When you build `List<OrderBook>`:

```
...
OrderBook book = CreateOrderBook(...);
list.Add(book);
book.ListIndex = list.Count - 1;
// Assign Owner here if that is needed.
...
```

Or better, use a helper for managing the list that cares for the book keeping of the index update:

```
public class OrderBookManager
{
    private List<OrderBook> list = new List<OrderBook>();

    public void Add(OrderBook book)
    {
        list.Add(book);
        book.ListIndex = list.Count - 1;
        // Assign Owner here if that is needed.
    }

    // Make this read-only if you want to ensure the manager controls all updates to the list (better design) but use it this way for higher performance.
    public List<OrderBook> List { get { return list; } }
}
```

The updated `OrderBook`:

```
public class OrderBook
{
    ...

    public int ListIndex { get; set; }
}
```

And then an sample event handler using this index:

```
public void StockUpdated(object sender, MyEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    OrderBook book = (OrderBook) sender;
    //Here use book.ListIndex to access the original list element.
}
```

What is your reason for having that index? Everything you need should be in the object. If you use this to manipulate the original list (such as removing this item from the list) then you have the problem of recomputing the saved index of all the previously stored objects.

If you are maintaining a parallel list with other objects, then you perhaps should consider a different design.

Comment: yes I have parallel list with other objects (double weight of each stock in index etc.)

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to use a signature of the form:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs a);
```

In your event handler you can use `sender` to find out which object raised the event.

If you don't have a `sender` parameter then I don't think there is any (reasonable) way to find out which object raised the event.

**Related**

- [How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx)

Comment: thanks, both answers are good but I have to select one correct. I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not provided automatically.

But the StockUpdated event should look like

```
 void StockUpdated (object sender, MyEventArgs e)
```

and you can cast `sender`to a `stock` and look it up in the original list. If you still need the index.

```
 void stockUpdated (object sender, MyEventArgs e) 
 {
    OrderBook stock = (OrderBook) sender;
    ....
 }
```

Comment: VS2010 generated such code for me: `private EventHandler stockUpdated()`. absolutely no parameters...

Comment: The somebody dropped the ball... and you're cooked.

Comment: fixed. yes I have `sender` argument. But I want to have index. With several tricks of course I can pass index in EventArgs....

Answer (score 0):

You can define in `delegate` of that event sending source (which is basically the suggested guideline by Microsoft. Having `object sender`, in other words, like a first parameter of the delegate's signature).

After make (say) a cast and determine in some `if/else` the *real* object type.